# How can I integrate $\int{1\over 2x+2}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, fractions

$$\int{1\over 2x+2}$$

## Method 1

$$\int{1\over 2x+2} = \frac 12\int{1\over x+1} = \frac 12 ln(x+1) + c $$

## Method 2

$$\int{1\over 2x+2} = \frac 12\int{2\over 2x+2} = \frac 12 ln(2x+2) + c $$

[Wolfram Alpha](http://140.177.16.21/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%282x%2B2%29) suggests the first method yields the correct answer, but why do the two methods produce different answers?

Comment: They are the same since $\frac 12 \ln(2x+2) + c=\frac 12 \ln(x+1)+\frac 12 \ln(2) + c=\frac 12 \ln(x+1)+d$

Comment: OHH whoops, forgot log rules and embarrassed myself.

Comment: Also, in case of definite integrals, when you map the function in the second method; the boundary changes and you will get the same answer as you have in the first method.

Comment: The only difference is $\frac12\ln2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this
$$\int{1\over 2x+2}dx = \frac 12\int{dx\over x+1} = \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{du}{u}} = \frac{1}{2}\ln{u} + c$$
where $u = x + 1$, $du = dx$. You know that
$$ \int{\frac{du}{u}} = \ln{u} + c $$